# Add each row in a single cell

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-tablix, ssrs-grouping

I have a requirement in ssrs report for display data like this.

[image]

I have to show 2 two rows data in one row in ssrs as shown below. Row count is unknown.
Please check another example.

[image]

Max two cell in one row in ssrs. I have to do this dynamically because I don't have any fix count in my data base table. If my table contain 3 rows it will display like first example but it it has 6 rows then it will looks like 2nd example.

Any suggestion how I can achieve.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I know to do this left-to-right, top-to-bottom flow style is to sort of hack it in with lists. To my knowledge, the built-in controls do not directly support it.

First add a couple of columns to the query output to assign row and column numbers to each data row. (Change the order by clause as appropriate)

```
ceiling(row_number() over (order by AddressField) / 2.0) RowNumber

(row_number() over (order by AddressField) + 1) % 2 + 1 ColumnNumber
```

Now add a list to the report. Group by the RowNumber field. Within that list, add two more lists side by side. They will use the same dataset as the parent list. These will represent the cells. The left 'cell' will be a list with a filter `ColumnNumber = 1`. The right 'cell' will be a list with filter `ColumnNumber = 2`.

Now add textboxes within each 'cell' to contain the address data and format them as you desire.